# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.nabil.myapplication.model.Gregorian.getDate()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gson, retrofit2

Trying to fetch the api data by using the library of retrofit 2 and gson, i was able to get the data based on the model variables which i created but in one model which i am getting is null point exception. I checked each and every variable whether it is initialized in constructor, getter, setters but everything was fine. In the debugging it is showing me null in the model of Date.java .Below is the java code and LOGCAT. Hope someone help me to find the solution.

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView fajrTv,dhuhrTv,asrTv,maghribTv,ishaTv,dateTv;
    Button btnSearch;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prayer);
        btnSearch=findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        fajrTv=findViewById(R.id.fajrTv);
        dhuhrTv=findViewById(R.id.dhuhrTv);
        asrTv=findViewById(R.id.asrTv);
        maghribTv=findViewById(R.id.maghribTv);
        ishaTv=findViewById(R.id.ishaTv);
        dateTv=findViewById(R.id.dateTv);
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SearchAPI();
            }
        });
    private void SearchAPI() {
        String mLocation=search.getText().toString().trim();
        keyboard();
        if (mLocation.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(PrayerActivity.this,"Please enter city name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(APIInterface.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            APIInterface apiInterface=retrofit.create(APIInterface.class);
            Call<Prayer> call=apiInterface.getPrayer(mLocation,method,school);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Prayer>() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Prayer> call, Response<Prayer> response) {
                    Prayer prayer=response.body();
                    String fajrMain=prayer.getData().getTimings().getFajr();
                    String dhuhrMain=prayer.getData().getTimings().getDhuhr();
                    String asrMain=prayer.getData().getTimings().getAsr();
                    String maghribMain=prayer.getData().getTimings().getMaghrib();
                    String ishaMain=prayer.getData().getTimings().getIsha();
                    String dateMain=prayer.getData().getDate().getGregorian().getDate(); //In logcat it is showing me null on this line
                    dateTv.setText(dateMain);}
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Prayer> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}});}}}}
```

> APIInterface.Java

```
public interface APIInterface {
    String BASE_URL="https://api.aladhan.com/v1/"; //For checking the json use "http://api.aladhan.com/v1/timingsByAddress?address=Riyadh&method=1"
    @GET("/timingsByAddress?address=&method=&school=")
    Call<Prayer> getPrayer(@Query("address") String address, @Query("method") int method, @Query("school") int school);}
```

> Data.Java

```
public class Data {
    @SerializedName("timings")
    @Expose
    private Timings timings;
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private Date date;
    @SerializedName("meta")
    @Expose
    private Meta meta;
    public Data(Timings timings, Date date, Meta meta) {
        this.timings = timings;
        this.date = date;
        this.meta = meta;}
    public Timings getTimings() {
        return timings;}
    public Date getDate(){
        return date;}
    public Meta getMeta() {
        return meta;}
    public void setTimings(Timings timings) {
        this.timings = timings;}
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;}
    public void setMeta(Meta meta) {
        this.meta = meta;}}
```

> Date.Java

```
public class Date {

@SerializedName("readable")
@Expose
private String readable;
@SerializedName("timestamp")
@Expose
private String timestamp;
@SerializedName("hijri")
@Expose
private Hijri hijri;
@SerializedName("gregorian")
@Expose
private Gregorian gregorian;
public Date(String readable, String timestamp,Hijri hijri, Gregorian gregorian) {
    this.readable = readable;
    this.timestamp=timestamp;
    this.hijri=hijri;
    this.gregorian = gregorian;}
public String getReadable() {
    return readable;}
public void setReadable(String readable) {
    this.readable = readable;}
public Gregorian getGregorian() {
    return gregorian;}//During debugging it is showing getGregorian "null" on this line
public Hijri getHijri() {
    return hijri;}
public void setHijri(Hijri hijri) {
    this.hijri = hijri;}
public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;}
public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;}
public void setGregorian(Gregorian gregorian) {
    this.gregorian = gregorian;}}
```

> Gregorian.Java

```
public class Gregorian {
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;
    public Gregorian(String date) {
        this.date = date;}
    public String getDate() {
        return date;}
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;}}
```

> LOGCAT

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nabil.myapplication, PID: 8752
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.nabil.myapplication.model.Gregorian.getDate()' on a null object reference
        at com.nabil.myapplication.PrayerActivity$5.onResponse(MainActivity.java:167)
```

Comment: Does `SerializedName` for `gregorian` is correct?

Comment: @Yeldar.N Yes, it is correct i double checked it.